# ¿Cómo realizar operaciones entre listas en r?

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo una series de listas con 82 data frames cada una, amabas listas son casi iguales, solo que difieren en que una está filtrada por los datos datos que exceden > 50 en una de sus columnas, para todos los data frames.

Quisiera saber si es posible realizar operaciones entre ellas, específicamente, relacionar este número de "excedencias" con respecto al número total de datos.

Si es de ayuda, aquí una muestra de uno de los elementos de las listas:

```
$ MOVILING_RochePM10.csv                                :Classes ‘spec_tbl_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   2191 obs. of  26 variables:
 ..$ X1                : num [1:2191] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
 ..$ Unnamed: 0        : num [1:2191] 357271 357272 357273 357274 357275 ...
 ..$ rowid             : num [1:2191] 3083119 3083120 3083121 3083122 3083123 ...
 ..$ date              : chr [1:2191] "1999-01-01" "1999-01-02" "1999-01-03" "1999-01-04" ...
 ..$ site              : chr [1:2191] "ROCHE (PM-10)" "ROCHE (PM-10)" "ROCHE (PM-10)" "ROCHE (PM-10)" ...
 ..$ EnvAut            : chr [1:2191] "CORPOGUAJIRA - CAR DE LA GUAJIRA" "CORPOGUAJIRA - CAR DE LA GUAJIRA" "CORPOGUAJIRA - CAR DE LA GUAJIRA" "CORPOGUAJIRA - CAR DE LA GUAJIRA" ...
 ..$ Latitude          : num [1:2191] 11.1 11.1 11.1 11.1 11.1 ...
 ..$ Longitude         : num [1:2191] -72.6 -72.6 -72.6 -72.6 -72.6 ...
 ..$ AveragingTimeHours: num [1:2191] 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 ...
 ..$ Year              : num [1:2191] 1999 1999 1999 1999 1999 ...
 ..$ Units             : chr [1:2191] "ugm3" "ugm3" "ugm3" "ugm3" ...
 ..$ COD_DEP           : num [1:2191] 44 44 44 44 44 44 44 44 44 44 ...
 ..$ NOM_DEP           : chr [1:2191] "La Guajira" "La Guajira" "La Guajira" "La Guajira" ...
 ..$ COD_MUN           : num [1:2191] 44078 44078 44078 44078 44078 ...
 ..$ NOM_MUN           : chr [1:2191] "Barrancas" "Barrancas" "Barrancas" "Barrancas" ...
 ..$ StationType       : chr [1:2191] "Fija" "Fija" "Fija" "Fija" ...
 ..$ CO                : logi [1:2191] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 ..$ NO                : logi [1:2191] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 ..$ NO2               : logi [1:2191] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 ..$ O3                : logi [1:2191] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 ..$ PM10              : num [1:2191] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 ..$ PM2.5             : num [1:2191] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 ..$ PST               : logi [1:2191] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 ..$ SO2               : logi [1:2191] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 ..$ Media movil PM10  : num [1:2191] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 ..$ Media movil PM2.5 : num [1:2191] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 ..- attr(*, "spec")=List of 3
 .. ..$ cols   :List of 26
 .. .. ..$ X1                : list()
 .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_double" "collector"
 .. .. ..$ Unnamed: 0        : list()
 .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_double" "collector"
 .. .. ..$ rowid             : list()
 .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_double" "collector"
 .. .. ..$ date              : list()
 .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_character" "collector"
 .. .. ..$ site              : list()
 .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_character" "collector"
 .. .. ..$ EnvAut            : list()
 .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_character" "collector"
 .. .. ..$ Latitude          : list()
 .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_double" "collector"
 .. .. ..$ Longitude         : list()
 .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_double" "collector"
 .. .. ..$ AveragingTimeHours: list()
 .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_double" "collector"
 .. .. ..$ Year              : list()
 .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_number" "collector"
 .. .. ..$ Units             : list()
 .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_character" "collector"
 .. .. ..$ COD_DEP           : list()
 .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_double" "collector"
 .. .. ..$ NOM_DEP           : list()
 .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_character" "collector"
 .. .. ..$ COD_MUN           : list()
 .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_double" "collector"
 .. .. ..$ NOM_MUN           : list()
 .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_character" "collector"
 .. .. ..$ StationType       : list()
 .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_character" "collector"
 .. .. ..$ CO                : list()
 .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_logical" "collector"
 .. .. ..$ NO                : list()
 .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_logical" "collector"
 .. .. ..$ NO2               : list()
 .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_logical" "collector"
 .. .. ..$ O3                : list()
 .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_logical" "collector"
 .. .. ..$ PM10              : list()
 .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_number" "collector"
 .. .. ..$ PM2.5             : list()
 .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_number" "collector"
 .. .. ..$ PST               : list()
 .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_logical" "collector"
 .. .. ..$ SO2               : list()
 .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_logical" "collector"
 .. .. ..$ Media movil PM10  : list()
 .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_number" "collector"
 .. .. ..$ Media movil PM2.5 : list()
 .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_number" "collector"
 .. ..$ default: list()
 .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_guess" "collector"
 .. ..$ skip   : num 1
 .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "col_spec"
```

La columna que me gustaría relacionar es la llamada "Media movil PM10", que se encuentra en cada uno de los elementos de las listas.

¡Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Hola LauraR si es posible realizar operaciones tomando en cuenta dos listas, existe en la library(purrr) funciones para trabajar con múltiples listas a la ves , ejemplo podrías calcular el % de excedentes entre el total de la base entiendo que algo así

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realizare une ejemplo tomando en cuenta la estructura de la base que tienes MOVILING_RochePM10.csv  y MOVILING_RochePM10.csv_50, aqui voy a hacer una suposición que si no se cumple no funcionaria, que es que el numero de elementos las listas ejemplo es igual al que queremos obtener la diferencia en % de las dos listas lo realizaríamos de la siguiente manera

```
library(purrr)
lista1<-Mediamovil2010
lista2<-SuperaPM102010
 
#nos daría el % de casos de la lista 2 correspondiente a la lista 1
map2(lista1,lista2,function(x,y) { length(y$`Media movil PM10`)/length(x$`Media movil PM10`)})

#Ejemplo suponiendo

#Realizando un ejemplo con la base de mtcars
#Creamos una lista que dependa del numero de cilindros 
mtcars_split<-split(mtcars,mtcars$cyl)

#Revisamos el numero de elementos en la lista
length(mtcars_split)
[1] 3

#Para realizar la operación necesitamos que las listas los valores a iterar
#tengan los mismos elementos por los que repetimos mtcars 3 veces
map2(mtcars_split,list(mtcars,mtcars,mtcars),function(x,y) { sum(x$disp)/sum(y$disp)})

$`4`
[1] 0.1566415

$`6`
[1] 0.1738023

$`8`
[1] 0.6695561
```

Este es un ejemplo de lo que deseas hacer con un data set que se encuentre en R

Comment: ¡Hola ruben! Muchas Gracias por tu respuesta. He intentado con lo que me has recomendado, pero me sale el siguiente mensaje de error: `Error: Index 1 must have length 1, not 26
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace`  ¿Debo inicialmente generar un split con cada uno de los elementos de las listas que me deje solo la columna "Media movil PM10?

Comment: Hola, Acabo de modificar el codigo para que solo haga la operación sobre los data frames que se llaman "Media movil PM 10" debería de funcionar de esa manera

Comment: Hola Ruben, nuevamente muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Tengo un incoveniente, ya que la lista sobre la cual deseo trabajar contiene 82 data frames dentro de los cuales está MOVILING_RochePM10.csv. Al cambiar el nombre MOVILING_RochePM10.csv por el nombre de la lista Mediamovil2010 y SuperaPM102010 y colocar el simbolo $ para escoger, me sale todos los nombres de los data.frames. No sé como podría especificar a toda la lista de los 82 data.frames, que necesito específicamente la columna "Media movil PM10" que contienen todos los elementos de la lista. Espero me entiendas, muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Laura , voy a tratar de explicar lo que entiendo a ver si es correcto; MOVILING_RochePM10.csv, es un data frame  que esta en una lista, con otros 81 dataframes , mi duda es cual es el nombre de la lista donde están los 82 dataframes  , ya que sobre esta debemos iterar y tomar el valor de "Media movil PM10" , que se encuentra dentro de los 82 dataframes

Comment: Hola Ruben. Sí, es correcto lo que dices, el nombre de la lista es "Mediamovil2010", y de la lista de >50 se llama "SuperaPM102010" dentro de ellas se encuentran 82 data.frames, cada uno de los data.frames tiene las mismas columnas. ¡Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Hola ya realice el cambio en el código, lo que tendría que suceder ahora , es que la función map recorra la lista de data.frames, y realice los cálculos sobre la columna Media movil PM10 dentro de cada data.frame

Comment: Hola Ruben, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, sin embargo, me sigue saliendo el mismo mensaje de error. `Error: Index 1 must have length 1, not 26
Call "rlang::last_error() to see a backtrace}".` 
:'( No sé qué hacer. Ya que me tomaría muchísimo tiempo realizarlo individualmente con cada data.frame.

Comment: Hola, Pudieras  ejecutar la función str(Mediamovil2010) para entender mejor como esta compuesta la lista

Comment: Hola acabo de realizar unas modificaciones adicionales al código, ya con eso debería funcionar. Saludos

Comment: ¡Hola Ruben! Ya me ha funcionado! Muchísimas Gracias!